# Problemas con Tablas intermermedias Pivot Laravel

Tags: laravel, mvc, eloquent, relaciones, pivot

**CONTEXTO**
Tengo una relacion many to many, asi que tengo 3 tablas

1. Avisos
2. Avisos_estados **(Tabla intermedia)**
3. Estados

Esto para tener un historial de los estados del Aviso

**Asi tengo las relaciones:**

Modelo Aviso:

```
public function estados(){
    return $this->belongsToMany(Estado::class,'avisos_estados','estados_id','avisos_id')->withPivot('activo','created_at')->wherePivot('activo', 1);
}
```

Modelo Estado:

```
public function avisos(){
    return $this->belongsToMany(Aviso::class,'avisos_estados','avisos_id','estados_id')->withPivot('activo','created_at');
}
```

**El problema:**

El problema surge cuando intento consultar Avisos que tengan estados activos (activo = 1), la consulta la hago de la siguiente forma:

```
    $id=1;
    $aviso =  Avisos::select(
                'Avisos.id',
                'Avisos.titulo',
                'Avisos.descripcion',
                'Avisos.imagen',
                'Avisos.created_at as fecha',
                'Avisos.vistas',
                'users.id as idUsuario',
                'users.name',
                'comunas.nombreComuna',
                'ciudads.nombreCiudad'
                )->join('categorias','categorias.id', '=','avisos.idCategoria')
                ->join('estados','estados.id', '=','avisos.idEstado')
                ->join('users','users.id', '=','avisos.idUsuario')
                ->join('comunas','comunas.id','=','avisos.idComuna')
                ->join('ciudads', 'ciudads.id','=','comunas.idCiudad')
                ->with('valoraciones')
                ->find($id);
               //Aca uso el modelo para traer los estados y usuarios relacionados con el aviso
               $aviso->users;
               $aviso->estados;
```

Esto me trae varios estados, de los cuales algunos no tienen relacion con el aviso al cual estoy consultando:

**Resultado** (Esta resumido, solo muestra la parte importante) [Respuesta sin resumir](http://vpaste.net/3Safm)

```
"estados": [//Estos son los estados que me trae como respuesta
{
  "id": 2,
  "descripcionEstado": "Cerrada",
  "created_at": "2022-09-02T19:37:45.000000Z",
  "updated_at": "2022-09-02T19:37:45.000000Z",
  "pivot": {
    "estados_id": 1,
    "avisos_id": 2,//Esta respuesta es incorrecta debido a que busque el aviso con id=1
    "activo": 1,
    "created_at": "2022-09-08T17:05:17.000000Z"
  }
},
{
  "id": 3,
  "descripcionEstado": "Desierta",
  "created_at": "2022-09-02T19:37:45.000000Z",
  "updated_at": "2022-09-02T19:37:45.000000Z",
  "pivot": {
    "estados_id": 1,
    "avisos_id": 3,//Esta respuesta es incorrecta debido a que busque el aviso con id=1
    "activo": 1,
    "created_at": "2022-09-21T15:12:42.000000Z"
  }
}
]
```

> La respuesta esperada seria:

```
"estados": [//Esta deberia ser la respuesta esperada, debido a que withpivot tiene un filtr cuando activo =1
    {
      "id": 4,
      "descripcionEstado": "Cerrada",
      "created_at": "2022-09-02T19:37:45.000000Z",
      "updated_at": "2022-09-02T19:37:45.000000Z",
      "pivot": {
        "estados_id": 2,
        "avisos_id": 1,
        "activo": 1,
        "created_at": "2022-09-08T17:05:17.000000Z"
      }
    }
   ]
```

**La pregunta es: tendre algo mal en las relaciones, deberia hacer algun tipo de filtro en la consulta?**

Esta es la estructura de la relacion
[image: Relacion manytomany]

Y aca tambien dejo lo que contiene la tabla estados por si acaso

[image: Tabla estados]

Y estos son los **unicos dos registros de estado que tiene el aviso con id =1**

[image: Aviso=1]

Como se puede observar en algun momento fue un aviso con estado = abierto pero despues lo cerre por esa razon el primer estado(abierto) paso a ser activo = 0

Comment: tienes las llaves del pivote al revés (en las relaciones). Además, me parece que la relación `avisos` en el modelo `estados` debiera tener la misma cláusula `wherePivot` para traer solamente los activos

Comment: Agradezco tu  comentario, lo resolvi colocando avisos_id primero, luego estados_id

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo pude resolver siguiento indicios en los comentarios, lo unico que cambie fueron la relaciones en los modelos, colocando `avisos_id` primero y quedo de la  siguiente forma:

Modelo Aviso:

```
public function estados(){
    return $this->belongsToMany(Estado::class,'avisos_estados','avisos_id','estados_id')
    ->withPivot('activo','created_at')
    ->wherePivot('activo', 1);
}
```

Modelo Estado:

```
public function avisos(){
    return $this->belongsToMany(Aviso::class,'avisos_estados','avisos_id','estados_id')
    ->withPivot('activo','created_at')
    ->wherePivot('activo', 1);
}
```

Y con esto me trae el estado activo que tiene cada aviso.

Comment: Insisto que cuando quieras traer los avisos dado un estado, tienes que añadir wherePivot(activo , 1)

Comment: esta agregado en ambos modelos, la condicion que el estado este activo.